# Testing a block with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some code (which I've stripped back for the purposes of the this example) and I'm looking for some advice on the best way to test it with RSpec.

```
ActionController::Renderers.add :liquid do |obj, options|
    # Set the mime type as HTML.
    self.content_type ||= Mime::HTML

    # Do some clever stuff....

    # Render the liquid layout.
    self.response_body = layout.render(obj)
end
```

This block is added to a set through the add() call and executed at a later time.

I'm looking to test the functionality of the block, to ensure it does everything I want it too, such as setting the correct variables (self.content_type) and calling the correct libraries (layout.render).

I've never tested the content of a block like this, so looking some friendly advice on how best to go about it, can I test the block as-is, or does it need refactoring into an external method which can be tested?

Comment: What you should rather do is test the effect the block provides. In a controller test, send a request and assert that the returned response is rendered correctly. You don't want to couple your tests tightly to the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stub out the addition of the Renderer, and test the call of the block from your code. In the code below I assume that the snippet you gave is inside a method named `register_liquid`:

```
let(:obj) { double(:obj) }
let(:options) { double(:options) }

before do
  allow(ActionController::Renderers).to receive(:add).with(:liquid).and_yield(obj, options)
end

it 'sets content type' do
  expect(subject).to receive(:content_type=).with(Mime::HTML)

  subject.register_liquid
end
```